# Cleaning tweets.csv in pandas: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this (idk why it is messed up)

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of          0  \
0       -1   
1       -1   
2       -1   
3       -1   
4       -1   
...     ..   
1599994  1   
1599995  1   
1599996  1   
1599997  1   
1599998  1   

       @switchfoot http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww, that's a bummer.  You shoulda got David Carr of Third Day to do it. ;D  
0        is upset that he can't update his Facebook by ...                                                                   
1        @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Man...                                                                   
2          my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire                                                                    
3        @nationwideclass no, it's not behaving at all....                                                                   
4                            @Kwesidei not the whole crew                                                                    
...                                                    ...                                                                   
1599994  Just woke up. Having no school is the best fee...                                                                   
1599995  TheWDB.com - Very cool to hear old Walt interv...                                                                   
1599996  Are you ready for your MoJo Makeover? Ask me f...                                                                   
1599997  Happy 38th Birthday to my boo of alll time!!! ...                                                                   
1599998  happy #charitytuesday @theNSPCC @SparksCharity...
```

The first column has the sentiment and the second has the tweet

To clean the tweets, I copied the following function:

```
def cleanTxt(text):
 text = re.sub('@[A-Za-z0–9]+', '', text) #Removing @mentions
 text = re.sub('#', '', text) # Removing '#' hash tag
 text = re.sub('RT[\s]+', '', text) # Removing RT
 text = re.sub('https?:\/\/\S+', '', text) # Removing hyperlink

 return text
```

When I try to apply it with:

```
str(df.iloc[: 1])
df = df.iloc[: 1].apply(cleanTxt)
print(df.head)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Entire error message: https://pastebin.fun/lZ6rG81tPv (I can't post without the entire message

Link to the csv: https://github.com/EmreTokyuez/Matura/blob/master/Data/Datasets/sentiment140/twitter.csv

How can I solve this?

Comment: For the formatting you need to call `head()` as a method.

Comment: Could you ensure the df is in utf8? If it's a CSV for example: `df = pd.read_csv(..., encoding='utf8')`. Sometimes that's the easy solution.

Comment: I opened it with this line `df = pd.read_csv("Datasets/sentiment140/twitter_fixed_values.csv", encoding="Latin-1", engine="python",)`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. Why the `df.iloc[: 1]`, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when re.sub encounters non string values. You should probably check closer for any special or escape characters in the string. I would simply print some of the tweets and check for any errors.